# Two pages named the same thing, on a different level but conflicting url paths in menus and direct links

Tags: menus, pages, urls

I've just changed some titles of pages and child pages around, simply I've got Work as top level page, and Blog as a top level, with Play and Work as children.

The paths are:

/work/

and

/blog/work/

However, if I create a menu directing the user to /blog/work/, either using a page tag in wordpress or a direct link it takes the user to /work/.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

http://msc-media.co.uk/ - Check out blog/work link, at the moment it's a custom format to point to http://msc-media.co.uk/blog/work/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, you can't "fix" this, as this is the internal behavior of WP.

You maybe could use some other slug like `blog-work`. Then go and redirect to your desired URI.

Comment: Had to change both the Slug and the title of the page.